# Precision, recall and confusion matrix problems in sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, metrics

I have trained a model in keras and I have made some predictions. To evaluate the performance of my model I have calculated the precision and recall scores and the confusion matrix with sklearn library. This is my code:

```py
final_predictions = model.predict_generator(generator_test, steps=steps_per_epoch_test)
rounded_pred = [0 if x<=0.5 else 1 for x in final_predictions]
test_precision_score = round(precision_score(y_test, rounded_pred), 3)
test_recall_score = round(recall_score(y_test, rounded_pred), 3)
test_confusion_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, rounded_pred)
```

These are my results:

```
Test confusion matrix :

 [[1555   13]

 [   9   49]]

Precision and recall:

Test Precision :: 0.845
Test Recall :: 0.79
```

Does somebody know why is the precision score calculated incorrectly? (It should be (`1555/(1555+13)` instead of `(13/(13+49))`)

Comment: Have you tried switching the arguments of `confusion_matrix()`. It seems to me that the precision and recall are calculated with 49 seen as true positive in stead of true negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `pos_label` of `precision_score` and `recall_score` are `1`.

```py
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix,precision_score,recall_score,classification_report

y_true = [0]*1568 + [1]*58
y_pred = [0]*1555 + [1]*13 + [0]* 9+ [1]* 49

print('confusion matrix :\n',confusion_matrix(y_true,y_pred))
print('precision_score :\n',precision_score(y_true,y_pred,pos_label=1))
print('recall_score :\n',recall_score(y_true,y_pred,pos_label=1))
print('classification_report :\n',classification_report(y_true,y_pred))

confusion matrix :
 [[1555   13]
 [   9   49]]
precision_score :
 0.7903225806451613
recall_score :
 0.8448275862068966
classification_report :
               precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.99      0.99      0.99      1568
           1       0.79      0.84      0.82        58

   micro avg       0.99      0.99      0.99      1626
   macro avg       0.89      0.92      0.90      1626
weighted avg       0.99      0.99      0.99      1626
```

If you want to get `precision_score` and `recall_score` of `label=1`. You can set `pos_label=0` to set class.

```py
print('precision_score :\n',precision_score(y_true,y_pred,pos_label=0))
print('recall_score :\n',recall_score(y_true,y_pred,pos_label=0))

precision_score :
 0.9942455242966752
recall_score :
 0.9917091836734694
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but setting ```python label=0``` I get incorrect results for the recall score. I get 0.991 and should be 0.844.

Comment: @Negreanu `0.8448` is recall score for `label=1`. You can see `classification_report` in answer.

Comment: Isn't "If you want to get precision_score and recall_score of label=0. You can set pos_Label=0 to set class"? instead of label=1? I got confused. The code snippets however are accurate.